# Is it possible to create a layer mask using a shape and fill it in with another color/pattern in Processing?

Tags: processing

Is it possible to fill a shape in with multiple colors/patterns if they are intersecting with an underlying shape or intersected with a line?

For example, we can see that the square has two different fills in the top-left half and bottom-right half.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [`mask()`](https://processing.org/reference/mask_.html).

This works on both `PImage` and `PGraphics` instances.

If you have an image of the top left diagonals (let's call it `diagonals`) and another of the green grid (let's call it `grid`), then you simply need to apply a masks (let's call it `gridMask`) one of the images, for example, the lower right triangle:

[image: triangle mask: upper left is black (masked), lower right is white (unmasked)]

```
grid.mask(gridMask);
```

What's what will be be revealed, what's black will be masked.

You could use the same principle with [`PGraphics`](https://processing.org/reference/createGraphics_.html):

```java
size(300, 300);

PGraphics diagonalsLayer = createGraphics(width, height);
diagonalsLayer.beginDraw();
diagonalsLayer.strokeWeight(3);
diagonalsLayer.fill(#114866);
diagonalsLayer.triangle(0, 0, width, 0, 0, height * 0.5);
diagonalsLayer.fill(#FFFFFF);
diagonalsLayer.triangle(width, 0, 0, height * 0.5, 0, height);
diagonalsLayer.fill(0);
diagonalsLayer.rectMode(CENTER);
diagonalsLayer.rect(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, 75, 75, 30, 30, 30, 30);
diagonalsLayer.endDraw();

PGraphics gridLayer = createGraphics(width, height);
gridLayer.beginDraw();
gridLayer.background(#d1e5f0);
gridLayer.stroke(#127e6c);
gridLayer.strokeWeight(3);
int gridSize = width / 5;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  gridLayer.line(gridSize * i, 0, gridSize * i, height);
  gridLayer.line(0, gridSize * i, width, gridSize * i);
}
gridLayer.rectMode(CENTER);
gridLayer.noFill();
gridLayer.stroke(#000000);
gridLayer.rect(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, 75, 75, 30, 30, 30, 30);
gridLayer.endDraw();

PGraphics gridMask = createGraphics(width, height);
gridMask.beginDraw();
gridMask.background(0);
gridMask.noStroke();
gridMask.triangle(width, 0, width, height, 0, height);
gridMask.endDraw();

gridLayer.mask(gridMask);

image(diagonalsLayer, 0, 0);
image(gridLayer, 0, 0);
```

[image: two graphics layers masked with the above triangle]